# Searching BST for value code

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

So I need to call the `contain()` function in `main`. And then call the `containsValue()` function recursively to see if the value passed in is in the BST. I am getting a return value of true when I search for the root value, however, I am getting false on any other value that I search. Any help would be great. Thanks

**BST.H**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#ifndef BST_H_
#define BST_H_

template <class bstdata>
class BST
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        bstdata data;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node() : left(NULL), right(NULL){}
        Node(bstdata newdata) : left(NULL), right(NULL), data(newdata){}
    };

    typedef struct Node* Nodeptr;

    Nodeptr root;
    int size;

    /** Private Helper Functions **/

    void addValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata value);
    void printInOrder(Nodeptr root);
    void deleteTree(Nodeptr root);
    bool containsValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata);

public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    bool isEmpty();
    int getSize();
    void add(bstdata value);
    bstdata getRoot();
    void inOrderPrint();
    void preOrderPrint();
    void postOrderPrint();
    bool contains(bstdata value);

};


/**Private helper functions*/

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::addValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata value)
{
    if (value == root->data)
        return;

    if (value < root->data)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            root->left = new Node(value);
            size++;
        }
        else //(root->left != NULL);
            addValue(root->left, value);
    }

    if(value > root->data)
    {
        if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            root->right = new Node(value);
            size++;
        }
        else
            addValue(root->right, value);
    }
}

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::printInOrder(Nodeptr root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printInOrder(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        printInOrder(root->right);
    }
}

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::deleteTree(Nodeptr root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        deleteTree(root->left);
        deleteTree(root->right);
        delete root;
    }

}

template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::containsValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata value)
{
    if (value == root->data)
        return true;

    if (value < root->data)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
            return false;
        else // (root->left !=NULL)
            containsValue(root->left, value);
    }

    if (value > root->data)
    {
        if (root->right == NULL)
            return false;
        else //root->right !=NULL
            containsValue(root->right, value);
    }

    return  false;
}


/**Public functions*/

template <class bstdata>
BST<bstdata>::BST() : size(0), root(NULL){};

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::add(bstdata value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new Node(value);
        size++;
    }
    else
        addValue(root, value);
}


template <class bstdata>
bstdata BST<bstdata>::getRoot()
{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "getRoot: there is no root in the BST" << endl;
    else
        return root->data;

}

template <class bstdata>
int BST<bstdata>::getSize()
{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "getSize(): There is nothing in the tree, size = 0" << endl;
    else
        return size;
}

template <class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::isEmpty()
{
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::inOrderPrint()
{

    if (size == 0)
        cout << isEmpty() << endl;
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printInOrder(root->left);
        cout << getRoot() << " ";
        printInOrder(root->right);
    }

}

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::preOrderPrint()
{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << isEmpty() << endl;
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        cout << getRoot() << " ";
        printInOrder(root->left);
        printInOrder(root -> right);
    }
}

template <class bstdata>
void BST<bstdata>::postOrderPrint()
{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << isEmpty() << endl;
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printInOrder(root->left);
        printInOrder(root->right);
        cout << getRoot() << " ";
    }
}

template <class bstdata>
BST<bstdata>::~BST()
{
    deleteTree(root);
}

template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::contains(bstdata value)
{
    if (value == root->data)
        return true;
    else
        return containsValue(root, value);
}

#endif
```

**BSTTEST.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BST.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    BST<int> B;

    B.getSize();
    cout << B.isEmpty() << endl;

    B.add(7);
    B.add(1);
    B.add(5);
    B.add(15);
    B.add(10);
    B.add(11);

    cout << B.isEmpty() << endl;
    cout << "Root of tree: " << B.getRoot() << endl;
    cout << B.getSize() << endl;

    B.inOrderPrint();
    cout << endl << endl;
    B.preOrderPrint();
    cout << endl << endl;
    B.postOrderPrint();
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << B.contains(1) << endl;
    cout << B.contains(7) << endl;
    cout << B.contains(78) << endl;
    cout << B.contains(11) << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In both the addValue and containsValue functions, those if statements should be if/else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return your result. As your containsValue() function iteratively calls itself, it will either find the value which returns a true or reach the BST's bottom which returns a false. Once the target value is found, it returns the true result to the function that calls it, which is itself, ONLY ONCE. The result is not stored nor returned. Hence it fails to return the final result all the way back to its first call. You need to add 'return' when calling the function iteratively. I've added the two 'return' you're missing.

```
template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::containsValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata value)
{
    if (value == root->data)
        return true;

    if (value < root->data)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
            return false;
        else // (root->left !=NULL)
            return containsValue(root->left, value);
    }

    if (value > root->data)
    {
        if (root->right == NULL)
            return false;
        else //root->right !=NULL
            return containsValue(root->right, value);
    }

    return  false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segment your code into if-else if-else blocks, as follows:

```
template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::containsValue(Nodeptr root, bstdata value)
{
    if (value == root->data)
        return true;

    else if (value < root->data)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
            return false;
        else // (root->left !=NULL)
            containsValue(root->left, value);
    }

    else if (value > root->data)
    {
        if (root->right == NULL)
            return false;
        else //root->right !=NULL
            containsValue(root->right, value);
    }

    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `contains` seems too complex. I would try something like this

```
template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::containsValue(Nodeptr node, bstdata value)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return false;
    if (value == node->data)
        return true;

    if (value < node->data)
        return containsValue(node->left, value);
    else
        return containsValue(node->right, value);
}

template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::contains(bstdata value)
{
    return containsValue(root, value);
}
```

A bit more effective iterative version:

```
template<class bstdata>
bool BST<bstdata>::containsValue(Nodeptr node, bstdata value)
{
    while (node)
    {
        if (value == node->data)
            return true;

        node = value < node->data ? node->left : node->right;
    }
    return false;
}
```